# How to consume this Rest service with Angular

Tags: angularjs, post, angular-resource

I've a simple Rest service coded in Java, see below my code

```
@POST
@Path("/add/")
@Consumes("application/json")
public String addUser(@FormParam("name") String name) throws JSONException{
    String val = "{user" + " : " + name +"}";
    JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(val);
    return jso.toString() ;
}
```

I'm trying to call this web service from Angular with factory and controller but it not working. See below my JavaScript code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);        

app.factory('FctStudent', function($resource){
        return $resource('http://localhost:10080/ClientAngular/Api/student/add/:name',
            {name : '@name'},
            {'save' : {method : 'POST'}}
        )
    });
    
    app.controller('SixCtrl', function($scope, FctStudent){
        $scope.titre = "Controleur SixCtrl";    
        $scope.save = function(){
            var donnees = $scope.data;
            var utilisateur = donnees.user;
            console.log(donnees);
            $scope.resultat = FctStudent.save(utilisateur);            
        };
    })
```

Could you tell me what is wrong please ?
Thanks in advance.

### Edit 1

Now I've this code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('FctStudent', function($resource){
        return $resource('http://localhost:10080/ClientAngular/Api/student/add/:name',
            {name : '@name'},
            {'save' : {method : 'POST'}}
        );
    });

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, FctStudent){
    $scope.titre = "FirstCtrl";
    $scope.valider = function(){
        var prenom = $scope.user.firstname;
        FctStudent.save()
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.resultat = response;
            })    
    };
});
```

And in my web console I get this :

[image]

Have you any suggestions ?
Thank you all !

Comment: What's passed in browser network tab?

Comment: What's the problem? Can you POST to your URL? Do you get any error on the console/debug tool?

Comment: You should use promise property of $resource, your function call should be like this: `FctStudent.save().promise.then(...) // you have omitted the promise part in your example.`

Comment: I've just added a promise but now in my console I get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined** Do you know how to resolve this issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`FctStudent.save` is an async request so it will return just return a `promise`. You have to wait for the rest(asycn) request to complete before you can access its response. Try the below code.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);        

    app.factory('FctStudent', function($resource){
        return $resource('http://localhost:10080/ClientAngular/Api/student/add/:name',
            {name : '@name'},
            {'save' : {method : 'POST'}}
        )
    });

    app.controller('SixCtrl', function($scope, FctStudent){
        $scope.titre = "Controleur SixCtrl";    
        $scope.save = function(){
            var donnees = $scope.data;
            var utilisateur = donnees.user;
            console.log(donnees);
            FctStudent.save(utilisateur)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.resultat = response;
            }
        };
    })
```

Comment: Hi all, I've tried ShankarSangoli's code but now in my web console I get in network tab this exception **java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. Always in network tab I get this TypeError **TypeError: FctStudent.save(...).then is not a function **. Thank you all for your responses